# Recoverability and cascadeless schedule in Database

Tags: database

Can you please help me clear up the difference between recoverable schedule and cascade-less schedule .

I know that recoverable schedule assumes that the first transaction writes should also commits.

In the other hand the schedule is cascade-less if it's free from dirty read.

Is the following schedule is recoverable ,cascade-less ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think misspelling on T1 transaction it must be Write(A) ?

This schedule is recoverable  because none of the transactions has yet **committed**.

But the following scenarios are nonrecoverable.

- If T2 commits immediately after Read(A) or
- If T3 commits immediately after Read(A).

Because T2 and T3 depends on T1.T2 and T3 reads A that writed from T1.If T1 should abort T2 and T3 would have read(and possibly shown to the user) an inconsistent database state.

Also schedule is not cascadeless **If T1 fails**,T2 and T3 must also be rolled back.